# Prove that $(\lambda^2,v)$ is an eigenpair

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let the characteristic polynomial of a 3x3 matrix be $-t^3+4t^2-6$. And $(\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair. Prove that $(\lambda^2, v)$ is an eigenpair of $A^2$ and $(\lambda^3,v)$ is an eigenpair of $A^3$. I think a good idea here is to use induction...but I only need to prove these 2, so I don't want to use a long proof. Is there a way (shorter way than induction) to prove that these 2 are true? I can write $A^2=AA$, and then solve for the characteristic polynomial for $AA$, and multiply them together to get $\lambda^2$?

Comment: You can ignore the characteristic polynomial they give you, this works in general. What does it mean for $(\lambda^2, v)$ to be an eigenpair? Since matrix multiplication is associative, what happens if you multiply by $A$ once at a time, since $(\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$?

Comment: You probably know that multiplication by the matrix $A$ acts on its eigenspace for$~\lambda$ as scalar multiplication by$~\lambda$ (this is immediate from the definition of that eigenspace). Then you can prove, indeed by induction, that multiplication by the matrix $A^n$ acts on that eigenspace for$~\lambda$ as scalar multiplication by$~\lambda^n$, for any $n\in\Bbb N$,

Comment: @StephenDonovan it means that the eigenvalue $\lambda^2$ is the eignevalue for $A^2$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A$. Could you outline the steps? Thank you

Comment: @Paradifil $(AA)(v) = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda (Av).$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks